# Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15

Tags: firebase, react-native

[image][image]Unable to build the react native project after adding firebase dependencies. PFA the screenshot for build.gradle and ./app/build.gradle[image].

If anyone experience the same kind of problem recently and can provide with the solution .Also have tried doing **classpath 'com.google.gms.google-services:4.3.15' Should be classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'** so if there is anything else let me know. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include the error log

Comment: @AbdullahZKhan have just attached in the post itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using any kind of VPN? Seems to be a network issue, your local gateway is not allowing you to connect to dependency servers.

Comment: Have to remove proxies from my system that solved the issue. thanks